# How can I merge 2 dot notation strings to a GraphQL query string

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to merge 2 dot notation strings into a GrahQL query with only javascript (it can be ES6/typescript).

For example, let say that I have an array of strings

```
[
    'firstName', 
    'lastName', 
    'billing.address.street', 
    'billing.address.zip', 
    'shipping.address.street', 
    'shipping.address.zip'
]
```

The expected query string output would be (white spaces are not important)

`firstName, lastName, shipping{address{street, zip}}, billing{address{street, zip }}`

I can convert 1 by 1 the dot notation to a query string, but how do I merge all of that together? I got a function that take `street.name` and output `street { name }`. So this function would do it

```
convertToString(inputString) {
    let result = '';

    if (inputString.indexOf('.') === -1) {
      result = inputString;
    } else {
      const inputArray = inputString.split('.');
      for (let i = inputArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i === 0) {
          result = inputArray[i] + result;
        } else {
          result = '{' + inputArray[i] + result + '}';
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(convertToString('address.street')); // address { street }
```

But then how would I loop through all strings and get only 1 GraphQL query string that combines the same properties into a group. The main issue is how do I merge the 2 dot notation strings without losing anything and without having duplicates (at this point, I can get this `address { name } address { zip }` but when this runs on the GraphQL server, only the latter is kept and so only the `zip` shows up in the result.

I tried creating temporary object that represent the structure, but that didn't work out so good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Revised Answer**

Based on your revised question and requirements, here's a revised answer. This will recursively build an object from nested dot notations, and then leverage `JSON.stringify` to build the query string (with some string manipulations);

```js
function buildQuery(...args) {
  const set = (o = {}, a) => {
    const k = a.shift();
    o[k] = a.length ? set(o[k], a) : null;
    return o;
  }
  
  const o = args.reduce((o, a) => set(o, a.split('.')), {});
  
  return JSON.stringify(o)
    .replace(/\"|\:|null/g, '')
    .replace(/^\{/, '')
    .replace(/\}$/, '');
}

const query = buildQuery(
  'firstName', 
  'lastName', 
  'billing.address.street', 
  'billing.address.zip', 
  'shipping.address.street', 
  'shipping.address.zip'
);

console.log(query);
```

**Original Answer**

I would suggest converting the individual dot notation strings into an object first, and then converting the object to a string.

```
function buildQuery(...args) {
    let q = {};

    args.forEach((arg) => {
        const [ o, a ] = arg.split('.');
        q[o] = q[o] || [];
        if (a) q[o] = q[o].concat(a);
    });

    return Object.keys(q).map((k) => {
        return q[k].length ? `${k} \{ ${q[k].join(', ')} \}` : k;
    }).join(', ');
}

const query = buildQuery('person.name', 'person.email', 'street.name', 'street.zip');
console.log(query);
// "person { name, email }, street { name, zip }"
```

Comment: Thanks this looks really close the solution that I'm looking for, however after updating my question (I just did so you probably didn't see it). If I run the buildQuery with the list of arguments provided in the question, the answer has some extra curly braces on the regular string `lastName {  }, billing { address, address }`, you can see `lastName` should not have `{ }`

Comment: I've updated my answer. It may be possible to improve the code a little, but it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just 1 little thing, when I try on jsbin, it throws an error on the `args.forEach`, it goes away after adding spread operator to args `(...args)`. Would you mind updating your answer.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I removed the spread when I saw you were passing an array of arguments instead, and didn't update the function call. I see your strings actually go three levels deep. This only works with two levels at the moment, so will need to be made recursive.

Comment: Oh I just saw your comment about the 2 levels deep, how hard would it be to make it recursive?

Comment: I really it to be recursive, so I can't accept the answer anymore. Would it be possible to update the answer? I'm not sure where to put the recursive in this function

Comment: @ghiscoding - well that was in interesting problem. I've updated my answer. Hopefully that works for you now, but let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Really amazing what you can do in less than 10 lines of code, it totally works, I even tried with 5 levels down and I'm really impressed. I tried working on a solution and gave up after 50 lines of code. I'm just really amazed with your simple solution. Thanks so much, it makes my day :)